# JSON to Object Mapping

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
"statValues": {
                                "c__TL_gattooi": {
                                                "value": 90.0
                                },
                                "c_cwc_gattooi": {
                                                "value": 3462.0
                                },
                                "c_gaw__oxcgattooi": {
                                                "value": 11.0
                                },
                                "c_odesb__ox_gattooi": {
                                                "value": 6.0
                                },
                                "c_odesb_cwdc_gattooi": {
                                                "value": 205472.0
                                },
                                "c_ach38_sax_gattooi": {
                                                "value": 1.0
                                },
}
```

Want to convert this JSON to a POJO to be mapped with jackson

Comment: So what POJO did you come up with that is not working?

Comment: "c__TL_gattooi": {"value": 90.0},
`c__TL_gattooi` this should be constant String If you are not having anything other than the value in braces why you are complicating things.Simplify it to `Map<String,Double>` as POJO if you can.If not then you need to create a type which will have value as `Double` attribute.and your class `statValues` will have attributes as you have mentioned will have type as `value` as written by you.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize given json from string `jsonSource` use something like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = mapper.readValue(jsonSource, Root.class);
```

I generated POJOs for you

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class Root {
    private HashMap<String, Value> statValues = new HashMap<>();

    public HashMap<String, Value> getStatValues() {
        return statValues;
    }

    public void setStatValues(HashMap<String, Value> statValues) {
        this.statValues = statValues;
    }
}

class Value {
    double value;

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If can give better names it's possible by remapping properties using `@JsonProperty`

To access value use something like `root.get("c__TL_gattooi").getValue()`, to get list of keys - `root.keys()`

Comment: The problem statement is "c__TL_gattooi" this kind of value are ramdom and they are atleast 700 values cant create a class kike this,

Comment: This also have to be mapped with jackson to need to use jackson here

Comment: Awesome dude you rocked it,